# c# create net core 3.1 service installer

Tags: service, .net-core, installation

I found 2 examples of how to create services with .net core:

1. based on .net core `console application`
   https://dev.to/pcmichaels/creating-a-windows-service-using-net-core-2-2-14ja
2. based on `worker service`
   https://codeburst.io/create-a-windows-service-app-in-net-core-3-0-5ecb29fb5ad0

But everywhere instal and start of service is doing by console commands.

There are examples of adding installer to service, but they work **only** with `.net Framework service`(both examples are provided above are not contain Design window with Add installer button): https://dzone.com/articles/create-windows-services-in-c

Has someone ideas about how to create an installer for .net core service?

Comment: It doesn't look like .net core contains any installer functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You typically "deploy" net core applications rather than install them. I think the focus from Microsoft is to direct you either use Azure, or your own servers and publish your code rather use a traditional "installer". You need to look at third party tools or roll your own for this functionality since its not provided out of the box